# Fitbit API :: Transfer heart rate data of user from fit bit supported device in to own Android application

Tags: android, heartbeat, tracker, fitbit

Any one worked on Fitbit API integration before then please give me your suggestion. I already go through documentation of Fitbit API for Android but
can not get any proper way for starting .

For this, I successfully login into Fitbit account with the help of
[fitbit integration for Android](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/11/fitbit-integration-in-android-login.html)

**My purpose is to access user's heartbeat data of Fitbit tracker**

but after log In what should I do to transfer heart rate data of fit bit tracker to my android app?
anyone have any proper way of documentation then please suggest us.

Comment: Have You got the Answer for this.

Comment: @Naveen Kumar Mishra  I'm not getting solution yet but for mah temporary use i integrate third party to retrieve fitbit tracker data .still looking for alternate way for this . if you have ,then plz share ...

Comment: No, i don't have that's why i asked to you. Can You Tell me how you able to make the third party integration.

Comment: connect me via mail  ..

Comment: what's Your mail id.    Mine is mail2nkmishra@gmail.com

Comment: you can see it on my profile ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70383/discussion-between-naveen-kumar-mishra-and-jigs).