# Android application integration with Fitbit ( Fitbit Tracker )

Tags: java, android, api, fitbit

I have an Android Application and I want to integrate my android application with
**Fitbit Tracker(fitbit)**. And I want to count the number of steps moved by the user by using that **Fitbit Tracker** and  want back the number of step taken by the particular user in my application, so I can calculate the amount of calories burn during the walking activity.

**Any help will be appreciable.**

Comment: Possibly duplicate of the following link Click here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187004/fit-bit-api-transfer-heart-rate-data-of-user-from-fit-bit-supported-device-in?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect your android app to fitbit tracker then you should call fitbit apis for accessing fitness data related to user. First do authentication process and then you can access users data from fitbit server. You can get more information [here](https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/Fitbit+Resource+Access+API).

Answer (score 1):

Its late but can be helpful.

Fitbit don't allow 3rd party app to get the data from the device. It is synchronized with the fitbit application on the phone and is available through the [Fitbit API](https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/).

During registration of application, if you dont have callback url, you can use your fitbit profile as the url & you can use your own name as organization name.

[You can check this out for implementation.](https://github.com/Stasonis/fitbit-api-example-android)

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to get activity data using the fitbit API but I'm only getting a public data and not my personal data. I'm authenticated and I can get my user data, but no matter what activity api I'm using, it returns always the same public data. any idea?